# Spring attempting to @Autowire my dependencies twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I have a Spring MVC application in which I'm trying to use @Autowired inside a class annotated with @Controller. In classes without the @Controller annotation, @Autowired works fine, as soon as I add the @Controller annotation, I get an enormous stacktrace at startup which mainly boils down to `No qualifying bean of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] found for dependency`

I'm sensing that Spring is trying to autowire my dependency twice?
I'll get to the prove further down in my question ...

In my `web.xml`, I'm loading both my contextConfigLocation and DispatcherServlet:

```
....

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

....

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ahpw-api</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ahpw-api</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

....
```

webmvc-config.xml contains just the bare basics to allow me to open up a Jackson JSON API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ahpw.api" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Cookies Filter to set cookies on JSON AJAX responses -->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean id="cookieInterceptor" class="com.ahpw.api.controller.COOKIEFilter"/>
    </mvc:interceptors>

</beans>
```

In my applicationContext.xml I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>

    <context:spring-configured/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ahpw.api" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <!-- Setup Jackson instance -->
    <bean id="jackson" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" />

    <!-- Setup RabbitMQ -->
    <bean id="nativeConnectionFactory" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="${rabbit.connection.timeout}"/>
        <property name="requestedHeartbeat" value="${rabbit.heartbeat}"/>
    </bean>
    <rabbit:connection-factory
            id="connectionFactory"
            port="${rabbit.port}"
            virtual-host="${rabbit.virtual}"
            host="${rabbit.host}"
            username="${rabbit.username}"
            password="${rabbit.password}"
            connection-factory="nativeConnectionFactory"/>
    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>
    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" reply-timeout="${rabbit.rpc.timeout}" />


</beans>
```

My class where the conflict is happening starts like this:

```
@Service
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AuthenticationController extends AbstractRPCPublisher<AuthenticationRequest, AuthenticationResponse> {

    @Autowired
    AmqpTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;
```

If I remove @Controller, everything starts up fine, but obviously the request mapping of `/auth` stops working.

If I put @Controller back and duplicate the jackson bean and rabbitMQ goodies in `webmvc-config.xml`, it starts up without errors, but it means having two instances of each resource, a copy of the configs in both WEB-INF and META-INF, not desirable.

Is there a way to instantiate my controllers via `webmvc-config.xml`, but tell it to ignore @Autowired so that my applicationContext can take care of them and if so, will @Autowire function as normal?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `@Service`? And is upgrading to a recent version an option?

Comment: If I remove @ Service, the webmvc-config is still trying to autowire the resources in the @ Controller annotated class it and the same stacktrace appears. I would prefer delaying upgrading to Spring4, unless there's no other solution?

Comment: Have you define the `ContextLoaderListener` listener ?

Comment: This smells like you're not actually including your `applicationContext.xml` file.

Comment: @NicolasLabrot, that fixed it for me, post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define the `ContextLoaderListener` listener which will create the root context of your web application and load the `contextConfigLocation` define in the `<context-param>` tags:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Thus bean defined in the `applicationContext.xml` application context will be available to the `webmvc-config.xml` application context.

I don't know if it is a typo but the `AuthenticationController` class must not be annotated with `@Service`, `@Controller` is enough.

Comment: I've since removed the `@Service` annotation as it was only used to experiment. ContextLoaderListener was missing in web.xml, strange how things were actually working except for when autowiring beans in controllers.

Comment: `applicationContext.xml` was not loaded, so `@Service` was not active and the `ObjectMapper` bean was not instanciated and so not injectable. Without `@Controller` and with `@Service` webapp launched without error, but behind the scene the `AuthenticationController` was not instanciated because the `@Service` was not active. With `@Controller` but without `@Autowired` webapp launched without error because `ObjectMapper` is not any more need.